# Store image in mongo db using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Instead of storing file directly into mongodb I want to store using mongoose library. How to use mongoose library using the code frame same?

Update:: Saved in mongoose library. Now it uploads all of the file but how can I just store only the docx file instead of image file. And uploading anyother file should say invalid file.

update 2:: Resolved with the issue. Now capable of only allowing docxx file. Now need to add filename with extention as mentioned in the comment section. How to use that part of code.

Middleware::upload.js

```
const util = require("util");
const multer = require("multer");
const GridFsStorage = require("multer-gridfs-storage");
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Grid = require('gridfs-stream');

const mongoURI ='mongodb://localhost:27017/file_uploaded';
const promise = mongoose.connect(mongoURI, { useNewUrlParser: true });
const conn = mongoose.connection;
let gfs;

conn.once('open',() => {
  gfs = Grid(conn, mongoose.mongo);
  gfs.collection('uploads');
});


var storage = new GridFsStorage({
  db: promise,
  options: { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true },
  file: (req, file) => {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            if (file.mimetype === 'application/vnd.openxmlformats- 
  officedocument.wordprocessingml.document') {
                resolve({
                    bucketName: 'words'
                })
                ***//Add filename inorder to maintain original final name with 
extention***
                //const filename = `${Date.now()}- 
   bezkoder-${file.originalname}`;
                //return filename;
            } else {
                reject(Error("File type has been rejected"));
            }
        });   
  }
});

var uploadFile = multer({ storage: storage }).single("file");
var uploadFilesMiddleware = util.promisify(uploadFile);
module.exports = uploadFilesMiddleware;
```

Comment: please [edit] your question to clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. have you tried experimenting with the [mongoose docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/)?

Comment: Change your mimetype for docx.  const match = ['application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document']

Comment: I edited my code but it is still uploading all the file types. I just want specific .docx file and rest of the file should say invalid file type.

Comment: Updated my code to accept only required file type. Now need to add filename in order to get custom file type. I have written the code in comment but its not working. How can I implement it?

Answer (score 4):

You dont need to use GridFsStorage. Try below code.

```
// file-controller.js

const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const multer = require('multer');

const router = express.Router();

const multerStorage = multer.memoryStorage();
const upload = multer({ storage: multerStorage, });

const imageSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    image: { data: Buffer, contentType: String },
}, { timestamps: true });

const ImageModel = mongoose.model('images', imageSchema);

router.post('/upload', upload.single('image'), async (req, res, next) => {
    const image = { data: new Buffer.from(req.file.buffer, 'base64'), contentType: req.file.mimetype }
    const savedImage = await ImageModel.create(image);
    res.send(savedImage);
});

router.get('/getImage/:id', async (req, res, next) => {
    const { id: _id } = req.params;
    // If you dont use lean(), you wont decode image as base64
    const image = await ImageModel.findOne({ _id }).lean().exec();
    res.send(image);
});

module.exports = router;
```

Serve route via express.

```
const express = require('express');
const FileController = require('./file-controller');
const app = express();

// Mongo DB connection code ...
// Serve static files code ...

app.use('/file', FileController);

app.listen(3000, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`));
```

Comment: Like in previously asked question how can I export so i can use in my route.js

Comment: Updated code. You can add your mongodb connection and serve HTML file. Do not forget post file via multipart data.

Comment: router.post('/upload', upload.single('image'), async (req, res, next) => {
    const image = { data: new Buffer.from(req.file.buffer, 'base64'), contentType: req.file.mimetype }
    const savedImage = await ImageModel.create(image);
    res.send(savedImage);
});

Can you please explain this line. Also I have edited my middle ware. Can you have a look whether its also good or not?